# You must deploy and link the following libraries before you can deploy a new version of Contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, ethereumjs

I made my custom library and try to using on my own project.
Below is the 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
module.exports =  async(deployer, netowrk) => {
await deployer.deploy(OptionStorage, ownerAddress);
await deployer.deploy(LDerivativeFactory);
await deployer.link(LDerivativeFactory, DerivativeFactory);
await deployer.deploy(DerivativeFactory, OptionStorage.address, XToken);
};
```

and in test cases, I am trying to use it as

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    optionStorage = await OptionStorage.new(owner);
    //library = await Library.new();
    //DerivativeFactory.link('LDerivativeFactory',library.address);
    derivativeFactory = await DerivativeFactory.new(optionStorage.address, quoteToken.address, { from : owner, gas : 50000 });
});
```

but in running the test cases I am facing the error

> Error: DerivativeFactory contains unresolved libraries. You must deploy and link the following libraries before you can deploy a new version of DerivativeFactory: LDerivativeFactory

How to resolve it? I try to link in the test cases as well then I ended up with different error

> Error: Error: base fee exceeds gas limit

Any help is admirable

Comment: modify your qus in more detail. Like which class is inherit and what is library class?

Comment: Truffle have some issues using async/await in migrations scripts https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/501. Perhaps in your case that causes problems in your tests.

Comment: @Ismael I don't think so it gets deployed by using async/await but not work with test cases but when I try with .then() it throw the error in deployment itself `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

Comment: @Ismael you are right when I debug both tx (one from async and from .then()) both give me no source code found the error. I don't understand why? at the end of the day, both ways are not helping me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the recommended fix in [issue #501](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/501), the problem that it causes is that the truffle's artifacts are not updated in the right order.

```
async function doDeploy(deployer, network) {
    await deployer.deploy(OptionStorage, ownerAddress);
    await deployer.deploy(LDerivativeFactory);
    await deployer.link(LDerivativeFactory, DerivativeFactory);
    await deployer.deploy(DerivativeFactory, OptionStorage.address, XToken);
}


module.exports = (deployer, network) => {
    deployer.then(async () => {
        await doDeploy(deployer, network);
    });
};
```